# Why did Rayquaza get a mega evolution?

Tags: pokemon

In the pokemon series, the trio of Groudon, Kyogre and Rayquaza both gained new powers after mega evolution was discovered, but why did Groudon and Kyogre get a primal form and Rayquaza got a mega, is it possibly because Rayquaza doesn't have a orb?

Comment: Rayquaza has a Jade Orb in the games (HGSS).

Comment: Were you looking for an answer from the video game perspective or from the anime/manga perspective?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've not watched the new Pokemon episodes or played the ORAS Games. So this answer is a culmination of research and not first hand information.

A google search lead me to a reddit where this has been discussed. [Why Rayquaza Didn't get a Primal Form](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemonconspiracies/comments/2tzfje/why_rayquaza_didnt_get_a_primal_form/). I also read through several forums and blog post that led to "plot" and the "game story". However, one of the comments seemed pretty logical to me.

> It's been stated that Rayquaza went Mega instead of Primal, because Primal means being in an anger driven state, only guided by instinct, which is why the Primals just try to seek for the most power possible while Mega Evolutions completely retain their state of mind.

According to the reddit,

> We know that primal reversion is when Kyogre and Groudon revert to their ancient states in which they had even more massive amounts of power than they do now, but Rayquaza was not like them and had enough power to stop the primal forms even in its normal state. **Zinnia provided this information in the Delta Episode while she is explaining the mural to you at the end of the story.** She also says that when a large meteorite was going to hit the Earth, **Rayquaza gained more power through the bond between it and the ancient people of Hoenn, i.e. mega evolution.**

Read the player dialogue with Zinnia to understand more. The story told between floors enumerate this. This also gives insight into the actual Mega Evolution process, i.e. Rayquaza was the first pokemon to Mega-Evolve.

Source : [Bulbapedia - Zinnia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zinnia)

> It was humanity's wish that brought about Rayquaza's transformation in the face of the rainbow stone... Yes... A wish... An intangible thing, invisible to the eye. Yet this wish bound people and Pokémon together, enabling the Legendary Pokémon to change its appearance... Doesn't it remind you of something? That's right... It sounds like Mega Evolution, doesn't it?"

**TL;DR** Rayquaza in itself is more powerful then the 2 Primals who reverted to their ancient form in anger and more power. Rayquaza, however went Mega to save the ancient people of Hoenn from another disaster in a seperate event. BSTs hwoever disagree with this.

Base Stat Totals:
**Rayquaza** 105/150/90/150/90/95 = 680 
**Rayquaza-Mega** 105/180/100/180/100/115 = 780 
**Kyogre** 100/100/90/150/140/90 = 670 
**Kyogre-Primal** 100/150/90/180/160/90 = 770 
**Groudon** 100/150/140/100/90/90 = 670 
**Groudon-Primal** 100/180/160/150/90/90 = 770

Comment: thanks for the great answer, could you also add in some sources that support the fact that being angry triggers Groudon and Kyogre to be primal form please? i don't remember anything from that during the game play

Comment: @Dragon Please read the bulbapedia page. There the dialogue between the Game MC and Zinnia is covered, where Zinnia tells the tale of Rayquaza in ORAS

Comment: @Dragon Please don't edit answers yourself, unless needed. The part you added was already covered in the reddit quote. I emphed that part.

Comment: sorry about that, i just thought maybe if i add that in it will be easier to sum up. i won't do it again, i apologize for my mistakes

Comment: Great answer. A note however: the BST part is completely unnecessary. The Anime largely ignores such things, and this is Anime.SE, not Arqade.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like Kyogre and Groudon don't go Primal because they're angry triggers. I feel like it's more like having a lust for power, or something. If there WAS a Primal Rayquaza, It would basically only be Mega Rayquaza, only more powerful. Plus, going Primal doesn't count as Mega Evolution, so you could use Primal Rayquaza AND a Mega all in one battle.That would be especially useful when battling a really strong trainer, like if you challenge the League again.